# 1.4 Django HTTP authentication

Tags: django

Starting in 1.5, you can do:

```
from django.contrib.auth.handlers.modwsgi import check_password
```

in your wsgi file for Apache HttpAuthentication. I am currently using 1.4, how would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.5/), this was a new feature of Django 1.5.
You may check the source code / implementation of `check_password` and see how it is done and can perhaps recreate it for 1.4, but I would consider updating the project to 1.8 anyway...